# Backup certain tables in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, backup

For my Android app i want to backup certain tables from SQLite database. This tables contain information about user. I dont want to backup the whole db.
I have found big amount of tuts about backuping, but all of them are about saving entire db.

P.S. I have found this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697192/dynamic-database-backup-for-certain-tables) but it has only one answer and is old as hell.
Hope someone will help me, thanks.

Comment: So you think that `old as hell` answers won't work anymore?!

Comment: @Rotwang, i didnt say that it doesnt work. i just think that maybe there is a better solution after 5 years

Comment: My preferred solution (dunno if it's a "better" one) is to save my table/s as CSV files. Because CSV is a universally adopted standard and it's very simple and has no overheads (while xml has tags and/or attributes)

Comment: @Rotwang, ok, thx, im gonna think about it

Comment: do you any solution for this

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran u can use 2 databases instead of 1. So, the first one will be "static" with must-have data, the second - with temporary data.

Comment: @P.Savrov can you please explain in detail if suppose database got upgraded like if i added extra fields to the table will it get updated

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran, IMHO, you are talking about migration. it's a totally different question. my problem was that I've got (for ex) 5 tables: A, B, C, D, E and two of them I wanted to backup (A, B).
So, I could create 2 databases (2 files with tables) - let say "static" and "non-static". then I can add A, B to "static" and others keep in "non-static". So I can easily backup "static" database, to save my tables A and B.